# How do I pass an array of structs (containing std:string or BSTR) from ATL to C#.  SafeArray? Variant?

Tags: com, interface, atl, safearray, atlcom

I have an ATL COM object that I am using from C#.  The interface currently looks like:

```
interface ICHASCom : IDispatch{
    [id(1), helpstring("method Start")] HRESULT Start([in] BSTR name, [out,retval] VARIANT_BOOL* result);
...
    [id(4), helpstring("method GetCount")] HRESULT GetCount([out,retval] LONG* numPorts);
...

    [id(7), helpstring("method EnableLogging")] HRESULT EnableLogging([in] VARIANT_BOOL enableLogging);
};
```

That is, it's a very simple interface.  I also have some events that I send back too.
Now, I would like to add something to the interface.  In the ATL I have some results, which are currently structs and look like
struct REPORT_LINE 
{
    string creationDate;
    string Id;
    string summary;
};
All the members of the struct are std::string.  I have an array of these that I need to get back to the C#.  What's the best way to do this?

I suspect someone is going to say, "hey, you can't just send std::string over COM like that.  If so, fine, but what's the best way to modidfy the struct?  Change the std::string to BSTR?  And then how do I,
1) Set up the IDL to pass an array of structs (structs with BSTR or std::string)
2) If I must use SAFEARRAYS, how do I fill the SAFEARRAYS with the structs.

I'm not familiar with COM except for use with simple types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a user defined structure is incompatible with the automation interface. You can probably work out a nested array or two dimensional safe array of BSTRs, but a more maintainable solution would be wrapping the structure as an automation object with 3 properties, then wrap the array as a collection that has an enumerator.

Neither IDL nor Automation define byte alignment for a struct. So you can have compatibility problems if your COM server has different struct alignment with the client. e.g. VB has a 4-byte alignment, while the #import in Visual C++ default to a 8-byte alignment. If you have a slightest chance in the future to use the interface in scripting, avoid using structs.

Suggested reading:

- "[Passing Structures through IDispatch" by Don Box, Microsoft
  Systems Journal, June 1996](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0696/activex0696.aspx).
- *[Design Principles for Collection and Enumerator Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skwy3ty0(VS.80).aspx)
- *ATL internals: working with ATL 8 By Chris Tavares, Kirk Fertitta page 392

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I am reading your suggestions.  One quick question: I played some more
and was able to come up with the following:
interface ISimpleCom : IDispatch{
 
 [id(1), helpstring("method Test2")] HRESULT Test2([in,out] SAFEARRAY(struct MyStruct) param);
};
where MyStruct is:
struct MyStruct
{
 
 long nLongValue;
 BSTR bstrStringValue;
} ;
This worked fine from C#.  It should not have based on your suggestions and reading (or is SAFEARRAY automation compliant?).
C#:
SafeArrayPlayLib.MyStruct[] myArray = new MyStruct[2];
com.Test2(myArray);
Regards,Dave

Comment: Thanks Sheng.  I won't be using this COM component with Script, just C#.  Thanks for all the help.  It's hard to get help on COM these days; it's old technology.